"missing required positional argument 'ctx'" in a Discord bot
I'm trying to make a discord bot, but I get the error from the title. This is my code:
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import logging


class DiscordBot:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.intents = discord.Intents.all()
        self.intents.messages = True
        self.intents.message_content = True
        self.intents.guilds = True
        self.intents.members = True
        self.intents.presences = True
        self.bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=self.intents)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot is ready.")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.send('Hello!')
        print("HELLO!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_dotenv()

    TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN_KEY')

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    bot = DiscordBot()
    bot.bot.add_command(bot.hello)

    bot.bot.run(TOKEN)

Here is a complete error traceback:
    ERROR:discord.ext.commands.bot:Ignoring exception in command hello
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/dimo/programming/discord-bot/mybot-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TypeError: DiscordBot.hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/dimo/programming/discord-bot/mybot-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
      File "/home/dimo/programming/discord-bot/mybot-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/dimo/programming/discord-bot/mybot-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: DiscordBot.hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

"I've encountered an issue where I'm missing a positional argument, 'ctx', but it's in the function." This misunderstands the error message. Please read What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?, or similarly in the Python FAQ. The argument is missing from the place that calls hello. What you have "in the function" is a parameter.

The basic problem
The scope is off. You're adding the command but it has self because it's in the class. When you use the decorator, you can't have self because then the first positional argument will be the class itself instead of the ctx.
The following (I tested it) works:
@commands.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('Hello')
    print("HELLO!")


class DiscordBot:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.intents = discord.Intents.all()
        self.intents.messages = True
        self.intents.message_content = True
        self.intents.guilds = True
        self.intents.members = True
        self.intents.presences = True
        self.bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=self.intents)
        self.bot.add_command(hello)

Also, why do you have a bunch of intents enabled if self.intents = discord.Intents.all() enables them anyway?
More in depth
If we were to print the parameters of the function in the decorator, with the following code:
    # Cut off for space, but it's inside the class for Bot you had previously
    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.send('Hello')
        print("HELLO!")


@commands.command()
async def Testing(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('Hello')
    print("HELLO!")

And if we were to edit the source code for the decorator to print the following:
    def decorator(func):
        if isinstance(func, Command):
            raise TypeError('Callback is already a command.')
        print(func.__code__.co_varnames)
        print(func.__name__)
        return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)

it would return:
('self', 'ctx')
hello
('ctx',)
Testing

The self is what causes the problem.
